# How to redirect request to specific page when URL match to category

Tags: .htaccess

I want to create .htaccess file where it should send all request to category.php if url match with category url as below.

Example:

```
www.example.com/category/online-chiler
```

Now here you can see that there is `/category/` in URL. So I want that whenever `/category/` is found then that request should be sent as under

```
www.example.com/category.php?cat=online-chiler
```

How to write this in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL and ensure that MultiViews is disabled, otherwise you'll lose the URL parameter.

For example, rewriting `/category/<page>`, where `<page>` is variable:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]*)$ category.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

As per your example, I've assumed `<page>` can contain any of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` or `-` (hyphen) OR omitted entirely. This corresponds to the regex character class `[\w-]`.

Comment: Here 'online-chiler' is not static it can be any, and so dynamically i want to redirect any value which are written after category/ url should be send to  as get in category.php?cat=...

Comment: How did you get on with this?